# Spring integration pubsub vs Spring amqp RabbitMQ pubsub

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I am working on a MicroBlog spring mvc hibernate application. I need to implement a publish subscribe functionality like twitter.

I am using RabbitMQ for messaging with Spring AMQP abstraction.

Everywhere I see on web the [pubsub](https://dzone.com/articles/pubsub-vfabric-rabbitmq-and) [examples](http://krishnasblog.com/2012/10/10/publish-subscribe-with-vfabric-rabbitmq-and-spring-integration-using-spring-amqp/) are given involving

> Spring Integration
>
> Spring AMQP &  RabbitMQ

I researched a little more on Spring-Integration & found that a publish subscribe can be implemented with it even without using RabbitMQ.

Now my question is

**Why do I need to use Spring Integration with [Spring AMQP & RabbitMQ] to implement a pubsub functionality. Why can't I just use Spring AMQP with Rabbit to do that?**

**Does Spring integration provide any additional features?**

My Spring AMQP & RabbitMQ configuration

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" virtual-host="/" host="localhost" 
username="guest" password="guest"/>

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:queue name="UserPostpublishQueue" />

<fanout-exchange name="broadcastUserPosts" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit">
    <bindings>
        <binding queue="UserPostpublishQueue"/>
    </bindings>
</fanout-exchange>

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" exchange="broadcastUserPosts" 
queue="UserPostpublishQueue"/>

</beans>
```

Test code in my controller

```
@Autowire
private AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;

try{
        amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(post);
        Post receivedPost = (Post)amqpTemplate.receiveAndConvert();
        System.out.println("received Post "+receivedPost);
        }catch(AmqpException e){
            //deal with exception
        }
```

Comment: Why just don't follow with some Google links and don't read about both a bit?..

Comment: If there was enough on Google I wouldn't have put up this question in the first place. Why don't you stop downvoting questions if you don't know the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Integration implements the patterns from http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/books1.html while using AMQP/RabbitMQ as one of its many transports.

I understand that `spring-amqp` is more the AMQP client functionality. If you don't want to use spring. Then we have a plain java client: https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html